# Why ActionBar Tabs show as Spinner on Tablet devices?

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock

I have made an app using TABS as navigation. On any devices like cell phones everything looks great but on tablet devices instead of tabs I see spinner ... why? I have tested that issue on AVD but everything seems to be ok. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have made an app using TABS as navigation.

From your question title, I am assuming that by "TABS" you mean action bar tabs. Action bar tabs were deprecated in Android 5.0, and they always had issues.

> On any devices like cell phones everything looks great but on tablet devices instead of tabs I see spinner ... why?

Because that's what Google wants, based on their response to [the issue I filed over three years ago](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24439) regarding this behavior.

> Any idea what to do?

Stop using action bar tabs. Use `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator (e.g., [`PagerSlidingTabStrip`](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)), or use `FragmentTabHost`, or use `TabHost` with views for tabs.

Comment: Thank You :) PagerSliding Works perfect ;)